# recursively replace text with sed

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

I want to use `sed` to replace each occurence of a particular text in a full source file tree. I've attempted the following:
`$ grep -rlI name2port\(\"Wan1\"\) . --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude=*.vxs | xargs sed -i 's/name2port\(\"Wan1\"\)/T_PORT_ID_WAN1/g'` but it doesn't seem to work, I think my sed cmd isn't correct.
 How do I do this?

The problem is, that the replacements just do not happen.

I tried this: `$ sed -i 's/name2port\(\"Wan1\"\)/T_PORT_ID_WAN1/g' ./rtos_core/jpax_switch/api/src/nms/switch_l3_route.c` but turns out, the occurences of `name2port("Wan1")` would not be replaced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`sed` uses BREs (*basic* regular expressions) by default**, which, for historical reasons - and surprisingly for someone used to modern regular expressions - require *escaping* of *certain* metacharacters in order to be recognized as such.

**In BREs, `(` and `)` are *ordinary* (literal) characters**, and only become special when `\`-escaped.

Therefore, to match literal `name2port("Wan1")`, use that literal *as-is* in a BRE (given that you also don't need to `\`-escape `"` instances):

```
sed -i 's/name2port("Wan1")/T_PORT_ID_WAN1/g' ./rtos_core/jpax_switch/api/src/nms/switch_l3_route.c
```

**If you're not concerned about portability, you can use `-r`** (or `-E` for *limited* portability to macOS, though with `-i` that won't work), which then **enables EREs (*extended* regular expressions), whose syntax and features are more likely to work as you expect**:

```
sed -r -i 's/name2port\("Wan1"\)/T_PORT_ID_WAN1/g' ./rtos_core/jpax_switch/api/src/nms/switch_l3_route.c
```

Note how literals `(` and `)` now *do* need to be `\`-escaped, lest they be interpreted as enclosing a capture group.

In this particular case, it is the BRE that requires less escaping than the ERE; generally, though, it is the opposite.